# How to add waypoint item in GeoTools

Tags: java, dictionary, geotools

When looking the examples of the Geotools, i cant find the examples about adding  waypoint into Map of GeoTools.

So how can i add the waypoint into Geotools ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to answer your question depending on what you intended:

A: GeoTools is just a toolkit; it does not provide an interactive map for adding a waypoint. There is no visual tutorial for the gt-graph module showing how to add a waypoint.

A: The gt-graph module does show how to find the shortest path between 2 (or more) locations; if you consider those locations waypoints you are set.

```
//calculate the paths
for ( Iterator d = destinations.iterator(); d.hasNext(); ) {
  Node destination = (Node) d.next();
  Path path = pf.getPath( destination );

  //do something with the path
}
```

To see this source code in context the documentation page is here:

- http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/graph/index.html